# Soap не авторизируется

Tags: php, yii2, сеть, api, soap

История: Хотя воспользоваться API от курьерской компании. Для работы они предлагают Soap. При тестировании с помощью ПО - проблем нет. При подключение со стороны PHP проблема возникает как будь-то не верный логин или пароль.

Технологии: Yii2, PHP 7.0
Подключение к конечному серверу( проверил с помощью списка функций)

**Пробовал:**

1. Выводить данные какие отправляю (в переменной $param - все врорядке)
2. Передевать в разном формате (stdClass...)
3. Менял кодировку (сейчас UTF-8)
4. и т.п

**Исходники:**

```
<?php

namespace backend\models\dhl;
use yii;


class Dhl24_parcel {

    private $dhlclient;
    private $authData;

    private $_cache;

    public function __construct($env = 'sandbox')
    {
        $dhlparams = \Yii::$app->params['dhl_parcel'][$env];

        $this->dhlclient = new Dhl24_webapi_client($dhlparams['wsdl']);

        $this->_cache = [];

        $this->authData = [];
        $this->authData['username'] = $dhlparams['username'];
        $this->authData['password'] = $dhlparams['password'];



    }
    public function getNearestServicepoints() {

        $params = [
            'authData' => $this->authData,
            'postcode' => '00999',
            'city' =>   'Warszawa',
            'radius' =>  10
        ];


        return $this->dhlclient->getNearestServicepoints($params);
    }


}
```

Ответ от сервера: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка то какая? Лучше с этим вопросом обращаться в службу поддержки

Comment: @ArchDemon, добавил скрин

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что нужно было обвернуть в еще один массив